# fread failure with WAVE file

Tags: c++, file

I'm using this [library](https://github.com/TaleTN/WDL/blob/master/WDL/wavread.h) to read samples of a wave file, in particular [this method](https://github.com/TaleTN/WDL/blob/master/WDL/wavread.h#L379):

```
unsigned int ReadDoublesNI(double** samples, unsigned int offs, unsigned int nsamples, int nchdest = 0)
```

the `Grv Kick Acoustic 01.wav` file I'm opening can be downloaded [here](http://www71.zippyshare.com/v/Gs6Wf6CS/file.html).

It seems to load the file correctly with this code (file attributes are correct, such as `m_bps`, `m_nch` and `size`):

```
WaveReader mWaveReader = WaveReader("D:\\Google Drive\\Samples\\Grv Kick Acoustic 01.wav");
const unsigned int size = mWaveReader.GetSize();
vector<double> samplesContainer(size);
double* mono[1] = { samplesContainer.data() };
mWaveReader.ReadDoublesNI(mono, 0, size, 0);
```

but once it reaches [fread](https://github.com/TaleTN/WDL/blob/master/WDL/wavread.h#L408) on the ReadDoublesNI, it skip to the end of the function, ending the for statement and returning immediatly. So I can't read any samples from the file.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: What's wrong on asking this kind of question? -2 and close 1? I've also specified all details.

Comment: calling `Open` from the `WaveReader` constructor makes you blind to any error that might have occurred during the `Open`. Try calling the default constructor followed by an explicit `Open` call instead (and check the return code) : `WaveReader mWaveReader = WaveReader(); std::cout << mWaveReader.Open("your_file");`

Comment: It seems to fix the problem. Make the answer, and you will get Accepted!!!

Comment: If `fread` succeeds, what the value of `nch` do you see?

Comment: @paizza: I don't know, the question looks fine to me, except that your test code is not complete, because `main` and `#include`s are missing, which can be very annoying as it turns a simple "copy & paste into editor and run compiler on main.cpp" into a more complex series of editing steps for anyone who tries to reproduce the problem on their own computer. You get bonus points for being very precise with your links and problem description, though, so +1 from me :) If you want to be extra nice, edit the question and add the missing code.

Comment: @paizza: Oh, and the question title was not particularly search-friendly, so I've edited it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code opens the file as part of the `WaveReader` constructor call :

```
WaveReader mWaveReader = WaveReader("D:\\Google Drive\\Samples\\Grv Kick Acoustic 01.wav");
```

This constructor calls `Open`, but doesn't handle the case where this call fails.

Instead, call the default constructor, followed by an explicit call to `Open`, and handle the error case yourself :

```
WaveReader mWaveReader = WaveReader();
if (!mWaveReader.Open("D:\\Google Drive\\Samples\\Grv Kick Acoustic 01.wav")) {
    // something went wrong - handle this appropriately, and don't use the mWaveReader object
}
```

That will at least handle the case where the file wasn't opened properly.